# React Native: This is not a function handling custom URL scheme

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, listener, ios8-today-widget

I have followed a tutorial on how to handle a custom URL scheme. This is the way I have it set up.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
   Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

handleOpenURL(event) {
   console.log(event.url);
   this.abc()
  }

 abc() {
   console.log("Hello World");
 }
```

`handleOpenUrl` function is being called, but function `abc` isn't. I click on a today widget button which opens my app with a custom URL from background to foreground. I am getting the error message `"this.abc is not a function"` on my iPhone simulator. I am new to react native and not sure why this is. I think maybe the script hasn't loaded or something when I go from background to foreground in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind `handleOpenURL` to your component.

Replace

```
handleOpenURL(event) {
   console.log(event.url);
   this.abc()
}
```

with

```
handleOpenURL = (event) => {
   console.log(event.url);
   this.abc()
}
```